# $\operatorname{Ann}(U +W) = \operatorname{Ann}(U) \cap \operatorname{Ann}(W)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that if $U$ and $W$ are subspaces of $V$ , then $\operatorname{Ann}(U +W) = \operatorname{Ann}(U) \cap \operatorname{Ann}(W)$.

I've tried this using the fact that $\operatorname{Ann}(\cup S_i) = \cap \operatorname{Ann}(S_i)$ and the fact that $\operatorname{Ann}(S) \subset \operatorname{Ann}(S')$ if $S' \subset S$.

Comment: This question is fairly straightforward in the context of Module theory. But I'm a little confused why you've tagged this as linear algebra. If $V$ is a vector space, what exactly is annihilating it?

Comment: http://planetmath.org/encyclopedia/Annihilator4.html

Answer (score 2):

Translating the question into words may help.

$\operatorname{Ann}(U +W) \subseteq \operatorname{Ann}(U) \cap \operatorname{Ann}(W)$ means: if $f$ is a linear functional such that $f(v)=0$ for all $v\in U+W$, then $f(u)=0$ and $f(w)=0$ for $u\in U$ and $w\in W$.

$\operatorname{Ann}(U) \cap \operatorname{Ann}(W) \subseteq \operatorname{Ann}(U +W)$ means: if $f(u)=0$ and $f(w)=0$ for $u\in U$ and $w\in W$, then $f(v)=0$ for all $v\in U+W$.